# Что означает такой вывод df?

Tags: linux, командная-строка

Подскажите, такой вывод `df -h` означает, что все место занято, а 12gb в колонке `Avail` - это место, зарезервированное системой?

```
Filesystem  Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/drbd0  1.5T    1.5T    12G     100%    /home
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это доступное место, 12G это меньше одного процента от общего объема 1500G. Такая специфика округления.

Comment: То есть, это место можно использовать, оно ничем не занято, правильно?

Comment: Правильно, available - доступно

Comment: @nup иными словами учим английский язык и арифметику.